# Can't get Indeterminate ProgressBar to display while ListView is Loading

Tags: android

I am loading a listview that lists all installed apps on the phone. I want the app to display an indeterminate progressbar (the spinning circular one) while the listview is loading.

```
     final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
            (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, ": Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
                applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.list_item, list)
        {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
                applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

            final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable);

            return convertView;
        }

        };
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Heres the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="16sp" />

 <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>

        </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Nothing displays while the listview is loading.... what am I doing wrong???

Comment: How you load data? How looks empty view?

Comment: Your calling lv a list view but it is a scrollview in the XML? More explanation needed

Comment: A ListView is not a ScrollView.  So, I'm a little confused by your code.

Comment: I provided the full code in the OP... the listview populates and displays just fine... the only issue I am having is in the setting of setEmptyView... the ScrollView is just there to hold the progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to load your data asynchronously:

1. When doing the initial setup only set the main ListView for the activity and set the empty view
2. Write an `AsyncTask` (link **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**) that loads your data asynchronously and populates your adapter when it completes
3. start your AsyncTask after initial setup
4. During the task execution your empty view (progress bar) should display and when the task completes, the ListView should be populated

Comment: Thank you for your possible solution... Are you sure that AsyncTask is the only way to achieve this though?? I was hoping there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: My theory is that you are loading the data in the UI thread, so it is essentially locking the thread and prohibiting the progress bar from displaying correctly.  So yes, I think the only way to do this is to do the initial data load on a separate thread.  AsyncTask is very easy to use.  You only need to override a few methods to get a working implementation.

Comment: Bug if you populate listview's adapter from a different thread, adapter will throw illegalstateexception saying data must not be loaded from a different thread. right?